# Nested list in XSD

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, xsd-validation

Is it possible to represent a nested list in XSD? I'm trying to represent something like the following:

```
ids : [ [item1_1, item1_2], [item2_1, item2_2] ]
```

Typically, to represent a single list, it looks like the following, but I'm having trouble generating a nested version like above.

```
<xs:element name="ids" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
```

Comment: Why invent some contrived, non-standard syntax when asking an ***XML*** question?

Comment: @kjhughes I'm looking to generate java objects based on these XSD's, and I'd like to represent the nested list in the xsd.

Comment: Thanks @kjhughes, I added a comment to your response below

Answer (score 1):

### Unnamed nested lists

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="ids">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="item" type="xs:string" 
                    minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

### Named nested lists

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="ids">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="nested" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="item" type="xs:string" 
                          minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I tried the first (unnamed) snippet and it generates a new class with, for some reason, only a single List<String> called item, rather than a List<List<String>>

Comment: It seems that your question is more a matter of tool (is it JAXB that you're using?) operation or configuration than XSD design.

Comment: Sorry if this is unclear, not very familiar with xsds. It looks like the project I'm working on is indeed using JAXB

Comment: I've added a [tag:jaxb] tag to your question.  I suggest that you update the title and the question to explain more clearly what you've tried, including a [mcve] that includes the JAXB configuration files.